# Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client when I want to display in ejs file

Tags: node.js, json, rest, ejs

I am trying to search in a json object for the data I need and place it in the ejs file but this error appear: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client.
I have to display the data in another way?

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
router.get('/:categoryId', (req, res) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < jsonSize(jsonObj); i++) {
    if(req.params.categoryId == 'mens' ){
      res.render('categories',
      {
        pageTitle: jsonObj[i].page_title,
        category: jsonObj[i].name,

      });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you execute `.render` function in the loop. You also need adjust you template to consume an array of categories.

```js
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
router.get('/:categoryId', (req, res) => {
  const categories = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < jsonSize(jsonObj); i++) {
    if (req.params.categoryId == 'mens') {
      categories.push({
        pageTitle: jsonObj[i].page_title,
        category: jsonObj[i].name,
      });
    }
  }
  res.render('categories', categories);
});
```